# how to mock i18next module in jest

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I'm setting up test environment for existing Vue project, and I decided on jest with vue-test-utils.

Everything is installed and in place, however when I import component I wish to test in .test.js file, and add component to test utils like so:

`let wrapper = shallow(Home)`

test suite crashes with error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'i18next' of undefined`.

I decided to mock i18next module but I have problems with mocking. My mock looked like this:

```js
jest.mock('i18next', () => ({
  init: () => {},
  use: () => {},
  t: k => k
}));
```

but I always get error:

```js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined

      35 |
      36 | i18next
    > 37 |      .use(Locize)
      38 |      .init(i18nextOptions);
      39 |
      40 | export default new VueI18Next(i18next);
```

Can somehow explain the proper way to mock i18next module so my wrapper object could initialize ? Also if I'm doing something else wrong, please point me in the right direction. Below is the complete test case:

```js
import { shallow, mount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Home from '../../src/app/pages/home/index/index.vue';

jest.mock('i18next', () => ({
  init: () => {},
  use: () => {},
  t: k => k
}));

describe('Home Component', () => {

  let wrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(Home);
  });

  it('something', () => {
    console.log('bleh');
    expect(wrapper.contains('div')).toBe(true);
  });

});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The error `Cannot read property 'init' of undefined` happens on the result of `i18next.use(Locize)` and not on the `i18next` object. Try updating your mock to:

```js
jest.mock('i18next', () => ({
  use: () => {
    init: () => {
      t: k => k,
      on: () => {}
    }
  }
}));
```

I used this file as reference to this mock: [panter/vue-i18next/src/i18n.js](https://github.com/panter/vue-i18next/blob/4efa0f11b0922c02b6f6a08218f4f3644ccdf648/src/i18n.js)

Comment: ```jest.mock('i18next', () => ({
  use: () => {
    return {
      init: () => { }
    };
  },
  t: k => k
}));
```

This worked partially to get another error message: 
`TypeError: this.i18next.on is not a function

      38 |      .init(i18nextOptions);
      39 |
    > 40 | export default new VueI18Next(i18next);
      41 |`

Comment: Even if I add on and t functions inside init, same error persist as in my comment above.

Comment: Try passing your i18n config to the `shallow` method, it should be something like this: `shallw(Home, i18n)`, I gave a similar answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48792562/1042324

Comment: Well... , I'm not sure. When I add it to shallow/mounted, in my karma+jasmine setup it doesn't do anything and still says i18next is not defined.

In Jest though, it doesn't complain about i18next, but throws bunch of ReferenceError: sessionStorage is not defined, errors. So even basic assertion like : expect(2+2).toBe(4); is not working...